# Make videos scrollable

Tags: codenameone

I have a scrollabillity issue in a Form, layered out by BoxLayout.y().

The form contains many Tabs (with fixed size), each tab of the Tabs can contain an image or a video (the video is inside a BorderLayout to scale it at the tab size).

If an image is shown, the scrolling up and down works correctly.

If a video is shown, the y scrolling is not possibile, I can only swipe to change the tab.

I suppose that the cause of this issue is that videos are native component (I used the Codename One API to show the videos).

How can I solve or workaround this issue? This is crucial for the app design. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: This happens on Android and iOS. I cannot test on the Simulator because when a Form contains a video the Simulator crashes because of the bug https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3360

Comment: As a workaround try using `video.setEnabled(false)` so it won't grab pointer events. I provided a potential workaround for the simulator issue in the issue comments

Comment: `video.setEnabled(false)` doesn't solve. Please see my answer.

Comment: That's a very good solution you came up with. Notice that in my suggestion I referred to the actual video peer and not the surrounding container so it might work if you find that peer and disable that. But your solution is elegant and good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `video.setEnabled(false)` workaround ([Make videos scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125522/make-videos-scrollable#comment116916305_66125522)) doesn't work.

I workaround in a different way, inserting the MediaPlayer container in a LayeredLayout container, and then placing a Button over the MediaPlayer. A generic empty Label doesn't work, but an empty Button works. Of course I have to override `calcPreferredSize` to make the MediaPlayer and the Button of the same size (or use a different approach to make them of the same size).

This allows scrolling, but prevents the tapping of the play and pause Buttons (that are over the video). I solved also this issue.

In short, this is my solution, tested on Simulator, Android and iOS (in the following code, note that `videoBtnsCnt` is a Container over the video, in which I inserted play and pause Buttons):

```
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(video) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(size, size);
            }
        };

        Container mediaPlayerCnt = new Container(new LayeredLayout(), "NoMarginNoPadding") {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(size, size);
            }
        };
        mediaPlayerCnt.add(mediaPlayer);

        Button allowScrollingLabel = new Button() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(size, size);
            }
        };
        allowScrollingLabel.setUIID("NoMarginNoPadding");
        allowScrollingLabel.addActionListener(l -> {
            Component responder = videoBtnsCnt.getResponderAt(l.getX(), l.getY());
            if (responder instanceof Button) {
                // it can be a play button or a pause button
                ((Button) responder).pressed();
                ((Button) responder).released();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayerCnt.add(allowScrollingLabel);
```